# Doubt in Numerical Analysis Burden and Faires

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, interpolation

I am solving a problem in this book about Error bound of Lagrange Interpolation.

we have $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is approximated by a second degree polynomial in $[2,\: 4]$ as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

My Query is $3!$ is already accounted in Step $2$

but at the end the author has again taken $3!$ in to account.

Is it a typo?

Comment: Never post unsearchable pictures.  Instead, typeset your question using *MathJax*.

Comment: Just a typo brother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it is a typo.

$$\left|\frac{f'''(\xi)}{3!}\right|=\left|\xi(x)\right|^{-4}\le \frac1{16}$$

The upperbound is $$\color{blue}{\left|\frac{f'''(\xi)}{3!}\right|}|(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)| \le \color{blue}{\frac1{16}}\left|-\frac{9}{16}\right|=\frac{9}{256}.$$